# How do I include a list type feature in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit() classifier?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to loop through a number of text documents and create a feature set by recording :

- **position list** in text
- **Part of speech** of keyphrase
- **Length** of each keyphrase (number of words in it)
- **Frequency** of each keyphrase

## Code snippet of extraxting features :

```
#Take list of Keywords 
keyword_list = [line.split(':')[1].lower().strip() for line in keywords.splitlines() if ':' in line ]

#Position
position_list = [ [m.start()/float(len(document)) for m in re.finditer(re.escape(kw),document,flags=re.IGNORECASE)] for kw in keyword_list]
        
#Part of Speech
pos_list = []
for key in keyword_list:    
   pos_list.append([pos for w,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(key))])
    
#Length of each keyword
len_list = [ len(k.split(' ')) for k in keyword_list]
    
#Text Frequency 
freq_list = [ len(pos)/float(len(document)) for pos in position_list]
    
target.extend(keyword_list)
                    
for i in range(0,len(keyword_list)):
    data.append([position_list[i],pos_list[i],len_list[i],freq_list[i]])
```

Where

- **target** : list of keywords
- **data** : list of features

I passed this through a classifier :

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.25,random_state = 42)

import numpy as np
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)


from sklearn import svm
cls = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=100) # Parameter values Matter!
cls.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = cls.predict(X_test)
```

But I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supervised_3.py", line 113, in <module>
    cls.fit(X_train,y_train)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 150, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, order='C')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 373, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

So, I removed all the list items by changing

```
data.append([position_list[i],pos_list[i],len_list[i],freq_list[i]])
```

to

```
data.append([len_list[i],freq_list[i]])
```

It worked.

But I need to include `position_list` and `pos_list`

I thought it wasn't working because these 2 are lists. So, I tried converting them to arrays :

```
data.append([np.array(position_list[i]),np.array(pos_list[i]),len_list[i],freq_list[i]])
```

but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last for loop of the feature extraction code you are trying to append to `data` a list of four elements, namely `position_list[i]`, `pos_list[i]`, `len_list[i]`, `freq_list[i]`. The problem is that the first two elements are lists themselves, but **individual features have to be escalars** (this is why the issue is not solved by converting the sublists to numpy arrays). Each of them requires a different workaround:

1. `position_list[i]`
   This is a list of float numbers. You could replace this list by some statistics computed from it, for example the mean and the standard deviation.
2. `pos_list[i]`
   This is a list of tags extracted from the list of tuples of the form (token, tag)<sup>*</sup> yielded by `nltk.pos_tag`. The tags (which are strings) can be converted into numbers in a straightforward way by counting their number of occurrences. To keep things simple, I will just add the frequency of `'NN'` and `'NNS'` tags<sup>**</sup>.

To get your code working you just need to change the last for loop to:

```
for i in range(0, len(keyword_list)):
    positions_i = position_list[i]
    tags_i = pos_list[i]
    len_tags_i = float(len(tags_i))
    m = np.mean(positions_i)
    s = np.std(positions_i)
    nn = tags_i.count('NN')/len_tags_i
    nns = tags_i.count('NNS')/len_tags_i
    data.append([m, s, nn, nns, len_list[i], freq_list[i]])
```

By doing so the resulting feature vector becomes 6-dimensional. Needless to say, you could use a higher or lower number of statistics and/or tag frequencies, or even a different tagset.

<sup>*</sup> The identifiers `w,pos` you use in the for loop that creates  `pos_list` are a bit misleading.

<sup>**</sup> You could utilize a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurrences of each tag more efficiently.